# Other expansion for positive Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-series

I was thinking of the following problem. Let $f$ be a Taylor expansion and $a_k$ the associated coefficients,

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~f(x)\triangleq\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k.$$

Let suppose that we have:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~f(x)>0.$$

Is it possible to find another expansion such that:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\beta_k(x)$$

with $b_k$ positive real numbers and $\beta_k$ (exponential?) positive functions ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's enough for this to work for $x>0$, and you change the sum for an integral, then this becomes Laplace transform $f(x)=\int_0^\infty dk b(k) \exp(-kx)$. For positive $b(k)$, $f(x)$ is of course positive, but I don't know if converse is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! My problem is that the $a_k$ are not necessary positive but $f$ is positive. I want to have another expression with only positive terms. Do you think that Laplace transform will work ?

Comment: Ah, sadly it won't. Inverse Laplace transform does not preserve positivity https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383996/is-inverse-laplace-transform-of-a-power-of-s-a-positive-function

Comment: Arh, thank you for these information !

Comment: The answer is trivial: take $b_0=1, b_k=0$ for $k\geq 2$ and $\beta_0=f$. You have to specify what functions $\beta_k$ are allowed. With exponential functions this is in general not possible, since in this case we will have $f^{(n)}>0$ for all $n$, so not all positive functions can be expanded into a series of positive exponentials.

Comment: Thabk you Alexander but here there is only $f>0$, we don't know the sign of the $a_k$.

Comment: The signs of $a_k$ do not matter, what does matter in my remark is $b_k>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is not possible. Here is an argument for this:

*Disclaimer: All inequalities hereafter are meant elementwise*

Let's consider a discrete version of this problem $x\in\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$. Then we want to find an invertible $N\times N$ matrix $\beta$ (different from identity), such that for every elementwise non-negative vector $\boldsymbol{f} = (f(0), f(1), \dots f(N-1))^T \geq 0$ we have
$$
\boldsymbol{b} = \beta^{-1} \boldsymbol{f} \geq 0\,.
$$
The necessary and sufficient condition for this is that $\beta^{-1}\geq 0$. Moreover, you require that $\beta_k(x)\geq 0$, which in discrete case translates to $\beta\geq 0$.

However, citing [Nonnegative matrix - Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix)

> The inverse of a non-negative matrix is usually not non-negative. The exception is the non-negative monomial matrices: a non-negative matrix has non-negative inverse if and only if it is a (non-negative) monomial matrix.

Where the [monomial matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix) is defined as:

> In mathematics, a generalized permutation matrix (or monomial matrix) is a matrix with the same nonzero pattern as a permutation matrix, i.e. there is exactly one nonzero entry in each row and each column.

Thus the only allowed transformation $\beta$ is reshuffling (and possibly rescaling) the elements of $\boldsymbol{f}$.

Comment: Thabk you very much Michal Jan !

Comment: But here you adress only linear combination of $f$. What about other transformations ?

Comment: If you want to allow for $\beta_k$ to depend on $f$, which is what I assume you mean, then I think @AlexandreEremenko's comment sums it up.

Comment: But in Alexander spoke only about exponential. My question was about the existence of a such positive family function. Do you know for this more general case ?

Comment: Except for $\beta_0=f$ and an infinite family of akin trivial examples, I do not.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)